# Log4j2 time based rolling

Tags: log4j2

The following is my time and size based file rolling appender

```
<RollingFile name="fileWriter" fileName="${LOG_DIR}/file.log"
     filePattern="${ARCHIVE}/file_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.gz">
    <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}"/>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
    </Policies>
</RollingFile>
```

To reduce the number of log files, I would like to make it rolling over by time, so that the files generated 30 days ago is automatically removed.

Could `DefaultRolloverStrategy` help in my case? If it doesn't, would anyone provide some suggestions? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the DefaultRolloverStrategy will do what you want. You should be able to configure:

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
```

As an alternative, you can also specify a Delete action something like:

```
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    <Delete basePath="${ARCHIVE}" maxDepth="2">
      <IfFileName glob="*/file_log-*.gz" />
      <IfLastModified age="30d" />
    </Delete>
  </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
```